# Output of Zero-forcing equalizer doesn't match theoretical calculations

Tags: digital-communications, equalization

Let's say I have a sequence $x[n]$ (signal) and perform convolution with another sequence $h[n]$ (channel), so:
$$
y[n] = h[n]*x[n] = \sum_{k}{h[k]x[n-k]} \leftrightarrow Y(z) = H(z)X(z)
$$

I'm looking for $C(z)$ such that:
$$
C(z)= \frac{1}{H(z)}
$$

So that I can compensate the channel:
$$
c[n]*y[n] = \sum_{k}{c[k]y[n-k]} \leftrightarrow C(z)Y(z) = \frac{1}{H(z)}Y(z) = 
 \frac{1}{H(z)}H(z)X(z) = X(z)
$$

Let's assume I know the channel $h[n]$ and I use that to obtain $c[n]$ using Zero-Forcing equalization.

My question is, if I do:

```
x = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7];
h = [1 0.9 0.3];
c = zeroforcing(h); % c=[-4.7619, 4.2857, -1.4286]

y = filter(h,1,x);
x_d = filter(c,1,y);
```

Shouldn't `x_d` be a delayed version of `x` ? But I don't seem to get that in my simulations.

(The way I obtain `c` is converting `h` to a toeplitz matrix and doing $c[n]=H^{-1}\delta [n]$ as explained [here](http://www.dsplog.com/2009/11/29/ber-bpsk-isi-channel-zero-forcing-equalization/):

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
c_1 \\ c_2 \\ c_3
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
h_2 & h_1 & 0 \\
h_3 & h_2 & h_1 \\
0 & h_3 & h_2
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 1 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0.9 & 1 & 0 \\
0.3 & 0.9 & 1 \\
0 & 0.3 & 0.9
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 1 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there might be something weird going on with that blog, but I only quickly looked. Here is the idea for the ZF equalizer:

1. Figure out the convolution matrix.

`convMatrix = convmtx(h, length(x));`

This will be a $9 \times 7$ matrix because the input vector $\mathbf{x}$ is length 7 and the output convolution will be of length $7+3-1=9$. It is not a square matrix but we can still get an inverse by computing the Moore-Penrose inverse (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse), which in MATLAB can be done by calling:

`invConvMatrix = pinv(convMatrix);`.

2. Choose your delay. `invConvMatrix` is a $7 \times 9$ matrix and we are multiplying with an all zero vector except for a single one at some delay $\mathbf{\delta}$. Lets choose the delay to be 5, so we have:
   $\mathbf{\delta}=[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]^T$.
3. Compute the ZF equalizer:

`zfEqualizer = invConvMatrix * d;`

4. Generate the received signal, and generate signal after equalization

`y = conv(h, x);
  z = conv(zfEqualizer, y);`

Now lets take a look at the resulting signals, and specifically notice where the equalized signal starts, right at the delay of 5 that we choose earlier. I hope this helps.
[image]

Comment: Thanks! I haven't managed to get it working the way you explained. When doing `convMatrix = convmtx(h, length(x));` I get a $7x9$ matrix. The pseudoinverse is a $9x7$ matrix though. So I picked $\delta = [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]$ ($1x9$) and did `zfEqualizer = d * invConvMatrix;`. A little bit different from what you said, why did this happen?

Comment: Also, the way of building the $H$ matrix is a bit different from what I've seen in some books (and in that blog)? The total impulse response tends to be 1 at central point and zeros to the left and right of the 1. In this case, I get all zeros to the left, a central 1 and then non-zeros to the right. Is that how's supposed to be? Thanks again!

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I fixed my typo. It should be that the result of pinv is 7x9. Your dimensions aren't matching mine because I am passing everything around as column vectors and you are as row vectors. I do that out of habit but if you read the doc on convmtx it will work with either row or column vectors. I hope that helps!

Comment: Also, about the construction of the $\mathbf{H}$ matrix...like I mentioned in my answer I had some doubts about that blog. I read it before and sometimes its accurate sometimes its not. Just googling to check gives the wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix. Scroll to the section on "Discrete Convolution" to convince yourself that it matches the MATLAB implementation.